# Trying to implement linkedlist

Tags: c#, linked-list, lock-free

```
        public void Push(Node newNode)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Node tmp = this.head;
            newNode.next = tmp;
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.head, newNode, tmp) == tmp)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public Node Pop()
    {
        Node pop=null;

        while (this.head != null)
        {
            pop = this.head;
            var oldcount = this.popcount;
            var newcount = oldcount + 1;

            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.popcount, newcount, oldcount) == oldcount)
            {
                pop = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref head, head.next, head);
                break;
            }
            pop = null;
        }
            return pop;
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------
    while (count < 10000) // 4 thread run this code
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                Node temp;
                if (freelist.head != null)
                {
                    temp = freelist.Pop();
                    headlist.Push(temp);
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
            {
                Node temp;
                if (headlist.head != null)
                {
                    temp = headlist.Pop();
                    freelist.Push(temp);
                }
            }
            count++;
            Console.WriteLine(count);
        }
```

I'm trying to implement lock free linkedlist.
I add `popcount` to avoid aba problem.
And I implement `Push` and `Pop` using CAS.
When I run this code, It is not working as I think.

```
    class Node
{
    public int data;
    public Node next;

    public Node(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

When I run code, a `Node.next` points itself.
For example, `Node.data` = 99720 and `Node.next = Node` So, When I go to `Node.next` It is still 99720 Node.
Can't figure out why it happen...

Comment: Your `Pop` method will always return null - that seems wrong

Comment: Removing `pop = null;` seems like a good idea to start. I'm also not sure what the purpose of `pop = this.head;` is

Comment: Is it just me or does anyone else think "[population count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight)" whenever they read `popcount` in this Q&A?  Poor choice of variable name; usually used to mean something else.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to build a lock-free stack. I'm not sure what (pseudo-) code you used as basis for your implementation, but your attempt to solve the ABA problem with popcount cannot work. When you are using a version tag to prevent ABA, it has to be *combined* with the pointer, i.e., the pointer and the tag have to be updated in a *single atomic operation*. Java provides [AtomicStampedReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicStampedReference.html) for exactly this purpose, but unfortunately .NET does not provide anything similar.

However, since you are working with .NET you have the luxury of a garbage collector, so you don't really need to worry about the ABA problem as long as you don't reuse your nodes.

BTW: your pop function is missing a loop.